# SQL Server stored procedure only returns last row of temporary table

Tags: c#, sql-server, api, stored-procedures

All the code that I have has worked with its intended purpose a few weeks ago, although I think I have deleted something by accident and now it doesn't work right. The stored procedure is suppose to return multiple rows of data, with each row having columns `TopicID`, `TopicName` and `PercentComplete`.

In the JSONController / API, the data is supposed to be concatenated into a singular string where each column is separated with `#` while each row is separated with `|`.

Example:

```
"4#Ideology#50|5#Morality#100|6#Religion#0"
```

What I notice now is that the stored procedure only returns the last row, so in this example case "6#Religion#0".

Am I missing code, or am I doing something wrong? Also in the JSONController/API, how do I concatenate depending on the number of rows that is returned from the stored procedure?

Stored procedure code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getTopicsForSubject]
    @SubjectID int,
    @StudentID int
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #SubjectTopics
    (
        TopicID int,
        Topic varchar(1000),
        PercentComplete int
    )

    INSERT INTO #SubjectTopics
        SELECT TopicID, topic, 0 
        FROM topic
        WHERE SubjectID = @SubjectID

    UPDATE #SubjectTopics
    SET PercentComplete = ISNULL((SELECT PercentComplete FROM StudentTopic
                                  WHERE topicid = #SubjectTopics.TopicID
                                    AND StudentID = @StudentID), 0)

    SELECT * FROM #SubjectTopics
    RETURN

    DROP TABLE #SubjectTopics
END
```

API / JSON Controller code:

```
private static string ExecuteSPGetSubjectsData(string queryString, string subjectID, string studentID)
{
    string json = "";
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbconn"].ToString();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        // 1.  create a command object identifying the stored procedure
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn);

        // 2. set the command object so it knows to execute a stored procedure
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // 3. add parameter to command, which will be passed to the stored procedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SubjectID", subjectID));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StudentID", studentID));

        // execute the command
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // iterate over the results, printing each to console
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                json = (string)rdr[0].ToString() + "#" + (string)rdr[1].ToString() + "#" + (string)rdr[2].ToString() + "|";
            }
        }
    }

    return json;
}
```

Comment: Your "json = (string)rdr[0] ....." line of code is just replacing the "json" variable as "rdr.Read()" loops through each record.  Instead of "json = (string).....", you will want to have "json += (string)......" - that will APPEND to the "json" variable each time, rather than replacing it

Answer (score 0):

You will need to append (+=, instead of just =) each record's values to your "json" variable - currently, your line of code is replacing the "json" variable value as it loops through each record (which explains why the final result has the values from the last record)

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    json += (string)rdr[0].ToString() + "#" + (string)rdr[1].ToString() + "#" + (string)rdr[2].ToString() + "|";
}
```